# Ruby, update twitter avatar and background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, twitter, avatar

How can I change/update the avatar and the background image using Ruby?

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = "xxxxx"
    config.consumer_secret     = "xxxxx"
    config.access_token        = "xxxxx"
    config.access_token_secret = "xxxxx"
end
```

The folder's name is "avis" ...it contains jpg files.

```
avis = Dir.entries("avis")
avi = avis.sample


puts client.update_profile_image(avi)
```

My response is:

```
rb:15:in `on_complete': media type unrecognized. (Twitter::Error::BadRequest)
```

Even if I put:

```
path = "/Users/.../avis"

file = File.open(path, "r")

file.each_line { |line| 
  puts line
} 
f.close
```

My response is:

```
twitter.rb:819:in `each_line': Is a directory @ io_fillbuf - fd:10 /Users/,,,/Ruby/avis (Errno::EISDIR)
from twitter.rb:819:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please post your full `error stacktrace`.

Comment: @Pavan I just did, does that help explain my issue better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you followed the api docs? i can't see you encoding anything base64.

> The avatar image for the profile, *base64-encoded*. Must be a valid GIF, JPG, or PNG image of less than 700 kilobytes in size. Images with width larger than 400 pixels will be scaled down. Animated GIFs will be converted to a static GIF of the first frame, removing the animation.

and what is that `'r'` in `File.read()`? are you mixing that up with `File.open()`?

Comment: yeah i'm not sure how to get it to upload the .jpg file. So I tried File.open, File.read, etc...How would you upload a .jpg file?

Comment: there is no such thing as uploading a file. you read the data from the file, then you send that data within your post request to the twitter api. as the documentation states you will have to encode it base64. so my best guess is to write something like this `client.update_profile_image(Base64.encode64(File.read('the-image-file.png')))`

Comment: is there a way to read a random .jpg file from a folder? I can't seem to get it to read from my folder. I edited the code for you to see what I mean...

Comment: it's not a good practice to change your questions half way through, others can't make any sense of the answers then. please change it back and post a new question.